# FineUploader does not show error messages

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

If have implemented fine uploader and can upload files. I have also set the allowed extensions to only allow PDF.

But when I try to upload and jpg for instance nothing happens.

Normally this is not a problem but i would like to see a message. This works on the fineuploader website but not for me.

Hope someone can help me.

code:

```
createUpload({ button: $('#dienstverleningsDocumentUploader'), 
endpoint:'/adviseur/profile/dienstverleningsDocument/' + '@Model.Adviseur.ServiceDocumentID',
messages: $('#dienstverleningsDocumentMessage'), allowedExtensions: ['pdf'] });

function createUpload(options) {
var button = options.button[0];//Should be a jQuery $(...)
var endpoint = options.endpoint;
var allowedExtensions = options.allowedExtensions || ['doc', 'xls', 'docx', 'xlsx', 'pdf'];
var sizeLimit = options.sizeLimit || 10000000;// 10Mb
var itemLimit = options.itemLimit || 10;
var messages = options.messages || $('#messages');
var complete = options.complete;

return new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    button: button,
    request: {
        endpoint: endpoint
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: allowedExtensions,
        sizeLimit: sizeLimit,
        itemLimit: itemLimit
    },
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
            messages.html('<div id="file-' + id + '" class="alert" style="margin: 20px 0 0"></div>');
        },
        onUpload: function (id, fileName) {
            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                            .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="Initializing. Please hold."> ' +
                                  'Initializing ' +
                                  '“' + fileName + '”');
        },
        onProgress: function (id, fileName, loaded, total) {
            if (loaded < total) {
                progress = Math.round(loaded / total * 100) + '% of ' + Math.round(total / 1024) + ' kB';
                $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="In progress. Please hold."> ' +
                                      'Uploading ' +
                                      '“' + fileName + '” ' +
                                      progress);
            } else {
                $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                                .html('<img src="client/loading.gif" alt="Saving. Please hold."> ' +
                                      'Saving ' +
                                      '“' + fileName + '”');
            }
        },
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                .addClass('alert-success')
                                .html('<i class="icon-ok"></i> ' +
                                      '“' + fileName + '”' +
                                      'succesvol.'
                                      );
                if (complete) {
                    complete(fileName, responseJSON);
                }
            } else {
                $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                .addClass('alert-error')
                                .html('<i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> ' +
                                      'Uploaden mislukt bij: ' +
                                      '“' + fileName + '”: ' +
                                      responseJSON.error);
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The home page and the documentation clearly state that Fine Uploader Basic mode does not provide any UI elements at all.  If you are using Fine Uploader Basic mode, it is expected that you intend to build your own UI and utilize Fine Uploader's API and callbacks.  All error messages, such as validation errors, are sent to an `onError` callback.  You can contribute your own `onError` callback handler and display the error messages yourself.

For example, suppose you are using [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) in your app.  Your instance might look something like this:

```
$('#uploaderContainer').fineUploader({
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    button: $('#dienstverleningsDocumentUploader'),
    request: {
     endpoint: '/adviseur/profile/dienstverleningsDocument/' + '@Model.Adviseur.ServiceDocumentID',    
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
        sizeLimit: 10000000,
        itemLimit: 10
    } 
})
    .on('error', function(event, id, fileName, reason, maybeXhr) {
        bootbox.alert(reason);
    });
```

Notice I'm utilizing the jQuery Fine Uploader plug-in in my example.  You should too as you are already using jQuery in your project.  See the documentation for more info on this plug-in.

If you want to use the default UI that comes with Fine Uploader and customize it a bit, you should be using `FineUploader` mode.  This is also explained further in the documentation.